# New Laptop and freshly installed SSD - Why does AS SSD Benchmarks records a slow performance?

Tags: ssd

I have just installed a new SSD into my new laptop (Asus G75VX) and made a quick test through the AS SSD Benchmark Tool. My SSD is slow (Q Series 256 GB), see results below:

> ```
>              Read        Write
> ```
>
> Seq -------------> 512.64 MB  -----  480.23 MB
>
> 4K   --------------->     14.15 MB  ----  36.43 MB
>
> 4K-64Thrd -----> 355.92 MB ----  173.70 MB
>
> Acc. Time ------> 0.143 ms ----   0.094ms
>
> Score ----------->    421    ----     258
>
> Total 896

I am confused and don't know whats the problem. Other rates on the web show a total score of 1006 points:( Can anyone help?

Comment: please post a picture of AS SSD Bechmark, this is easier to read for us.

Comment: Would help if you included the laptop model or basic specs;  "new" does not necessarily equate to "fast".